# Why is the normal stylesheet taking preference over the print stylesheet when printing?

Tags: css, printing

I am attempting to bypass the need for a PDF component by building a good print stylesheet.

I have two CSS files, `site.css` and `print.css`. They are loaded via the following:

```
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

`site.css` is a large, long and boring css file with the addition of

```
.printonly
{
    display: none;
}
```

This is applied to elements in the document I have added for the sole intention of printing which I do not want on the page. It only exists in the site.css file.

When I have the image loaded through `<img class="printonly" src="image.png" id="logo" alt="logo"/>` It is not visible on the printed sheet.

If I drop the `class="printonly"`, then it places the picture on the printed page just fine.

This makes me believe that it is picking up `site.css` even when trying to print.

Is there any way around this, or can anyone suggest anything?

---

For completion sake, I have included the entire print.css, however, I am not sure it is really needed:

```
body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm; }

#logo {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%; }

.noprint {
    display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make the first stylesheet for screen media only, or you can change the display value for those images back to inline in your print media stylesheet.

Comment: Ahh.... Can't believe how simple it was! Adding media="screen" to the first one works just fine! ... Once again, I feel silly. I just thought print was used when printing, I had no idea it would use both. +1/answer when I can.